# How to flash a Nano framework project on esp32

Tags: nanoframework

*Am getting error when am trying to write this command on cmd:*

**nanoff --update --target ESP32_WROOM_32 --serialport COM6**

*Error Message below:*

**Connected to ESP32 ESP32D0WDQ6 (revision 1) with MAC address 8CAAB5943E9C**

**features WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None**

**Flash information: manufacturer 0x32 device 0x16406 size 4MB**

**Trying to find ESP32_WROOM_32 in developement repository...**

**Trying to find ESP32_WROOM_32 in community targets repository...Error E9005**

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the latest nanoff version installed.

Comment: Did the above helped you? If yes, please up vote the answer.

Comment: Hi have the same problem. First I run the command: dotnet tool update nanofirmwareflasher --global to update nanoff to version v1.13.0+a694210f01 but the same error E9005 occurs

Comment: nanofirmwareflasher is the old tool. You should be using  nanoff

Comment: Thank you. With the new tool I've succesfully flashed my esp32.

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt at `dotnet tool update nanoff --global` failed.

This is what I did to make it work:

First uninstall the old nanofirmwareflasher:

```
dotnet tool uninstall nanofirmwareflasher  --global
```

Then install the new flasher "nanoff":

```
dotnet tool install nanoff --global
```

You can, periodically, get it updated by:

```
dotnet tool update nanoff --global
```